# File path in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my first question on stack overflow.
I need to create a path for images and path should be like this **pages/assets/images/Topic02/T02P08/L1T2_P8_2a_Normal.png** . So I am breaking this string into 2 parts.

#### 1st

```
 var dummyUrl1= "pages/assets/images/Topic02/T02P08/L1T2_P8_2";
```

#### 2nd

```
var dummyUrl2="_Normal.png";
```

I just need to change 2a with 2b,2c,2d etc according to my need. So I stored these letters into an array. And picking them. And then I am making a new string string in this manner,

`var currentImgUrl= dummyUrl1+arr[imageId]+dummyUrl2;` 
where `arr=['a','b','c','d','e']`
So value of currentImgUrl should be like this,
**"pages/assets/images/Topic02/T02P08/L1T2_P8_2b_Normal.png"** but I am getting value in this manner ,
"http://192.168.86.91/Tarun/AXON/DfMAWorking/pages/assets/images/Topic02/T02P08/L1T2_P8_2a_Normal.png"

I tried this code:

```
$(".clickme,.innerText").mouseenter(function(){
     var arr = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
     var dummyUrl1= "pages/assets/images/Topic02/T02P08/L1T2_P8_2";
     var dummyUrl2="_Normal.png";
     var getImageId = $(this).attr("id");
     var imageId= getImageId.substring(3,4);

     var currentImgUrl= dummyUrl1+arr[imageId]+dummyUrl2;
     console.log("Current Image should be : "+currentImgUrl);
});
```

Comment: So I think this is related to relative path.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is relative, if you want `http://192.168.86.91/pages/assets/...Normal.png"`, add a / at the beginning of dummyUrl1 `dummyUrl1= "/pages/assets/images/Topic02/T02P08/L1T2_P8_2";`

Comment: I did but now I am getting       /http://192.168.86.91/Tarun/Philips/DfMAWorking/pages/assets/images/Topic02/T02P08/L1T2_P8_2c_Normal.png